# When import file, it reads it as CSV and garbles the data

Tags: parquet, h2o, sparkling-water

Running sparkling-shell (tried versions 2.2.2 - 2.2.6) on with Spark2 (under CDH 5.13 under Linux 7.2).  CSV and ZIP files import fine, but when I tried to import a Parquet file, it reads it as CSV and garbles the data.

Anyone has any suggestions?

Shankar

Answer (score 0):

Sparkling-water 2.2.7 seems to work better.  However, it was looking for the "h20.jar" file for the parsers.  So, installed the latest version of h2o, then modified the "sparkling-shell" script to include the h2o.jar file while launching the spark-shell.

Shankar.